# Animating Reloading of UITableView

Tags: iphone, uitableview, animation, swipe

I am trying to animate table rows in a `UITableView` in an iPhone project as I swipe across the screen to reload the data.

When I disable animations and only call `reloadData`, table continues responding to swipe gestures.

When I add animations with the `reloadSections:WithRowAnimation:` method, table stops responding to swipes, and only the navigation bar at the top responds to swipes.

Another change is that, table starts responding to selection and I have to manually disable it again. I suspect these two issues might be related.

I am using the swipe detection code over here btw: [1](http://www.ericd.net/2009/07/iphone-previous-example-with-touches.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My code for managing the gesture was in a `UIView` which contained another UIView which in turn contains the `UITableView`. It turns out that the user interaction of the `UIView` which is the superview of the `UITableView` was Enabled. Setting it to disabled caused the gesture to move up in the responder chain, and solve the problem.